# IOS export qr code data

Tags: ios, qr-code

[Ios 7 QR code](http://www.ama-dev.com/iphone-qr-code-library-ios-7/)

I have the code above. 
[1](http://www.ama-dev.com/iphone-qr-code-library-ios-7/)Currently when i read a "QR image" it opens up notes and displays the encoded text. Is it possible that when i read the "QR image", it does not open up the notes app, but instead the encoded text is displayed in my own "view-controller".

If its possible how can i do so, i really have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you have posted is from my blog.

So take a look at the following method:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects
   fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    for(AVMetadataObject *current in metadataObjects) {
        if([current isKindOfClass:[AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject class]]) {
            if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(scanViewController:didSuccessfullyScan:)]) {
                NSString *scannedValue = [((AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *) current) stringValue];
                [self.delegate scanViewController:self didSuccessfullyScan:scannedValue];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`scannedValue`does contain the data which is encoded within the QR-/Bar-/EAN-,...Code. You can do whatever you want with it.
Create your own ViewController and implement the `scanViewController:didSuccessfullyScan:` method. You will get the `scannedValue`via delegate call and can either display the value or do anything you want to do with it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I really did not realize the answer was already in the code itself. I will try it.